# Is there any endpoints (API ) for listing event in microsoft graph REST API

Tags: python, api, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

```
List Events Of Calendar
     - with or without recurring events
     - recurring as separate events
     - Search by attendees
```

How can I list or get events by this pattern in the Microsoft calendar using the Microsoft graph?

I have used below link for getting event by the extended property is there any other endpoints so I can find an event by above parameters.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first two cases, you can call [calendarview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) or [getEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get-event?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) - you can customize these responses [using OData query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters). To filter by endpoint property, the link shared above should give you the right properties.

Let me know if this helps and if you have further questions,